# Get unique Key from Firebase Database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing to the RealTime Database using a db file. The field generates a unique id key and I need to pass that key back to the parent file.

My db function:

```
    export const doCreateCompany = name =>
  db
    .ref(`company`)
    .push()
    .set({ name });
```

My calling function is as follows:

```
db.doCreateCompany(companyName).then((e) => {
          console.log("Key", e);
```

I need to write another function immediately following using the unique key. Any help is great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your function to still return a promise that resolves when the set() is complete, and *also* have access to the push ID, try something like this:

```
export const doCreateCompany = name => {
    const ref = db.ref('company').push()
    return ref.set({ name }).then(() => {
        return Promise.resolve(ref.key)
    })
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
doCreateCompany(name).then(key => {
    // key is the push id here
})
```

Comment: I would like to use a Promise but this is giving an unexpected error

Comment: Sorry, there was a syntax error in the code.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the call to `push()` from the `set(...)`:

```
export const doCreateCompany = name =>
  var ref = db.ref(`company`).push();
  var key = ref.key;
  ref.set({ name });
```

Now you can return the `key` to whoever called the function.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to keep the function returning a promise that resolves when the set() is complete, but also have access to the key from that promise.

Comment: Thank you. This did it. I had tried breaking it a part kind of like this but with no result. What I also have to do is remove the .then((){}) section. Thanks